# RavenDb add property using RQL

Tags: ravendb-studio, ravendb5

Is there a way to add a property to all documents in a collection using RQL(Patch)?

> Bulk-Insert is a possible solution, but it's required to write c#
> code, which is not a fast solution to achieve, specially in a matter that you need to
> manipulate your data and need to go back and forth for many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a new field with **[Patching](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.2/Csharp/client-api/operations/patching/single-document)**.

Can read about it [here](https://ravendb.net/learn/inside-ravendb-book/reader/4.0/2-zero-to-ravendb#patching-documents) in [RavenDB Book](https://ravendb.net/learn/inside-ravendb-book/reader/4.0/2-zero-to-ravendb#patching-documents)
Under Patching Documents

i.e.
The following **[RQL](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.2/csharp/indexes/querying/what-is-rql)** will add the new field `MyNewPropery` to all documents in the Categories collection:

```
from Categories
update {
    this.MyNewPropery = "some content";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To complete @Danielle answer, I thought it would be useful to add this line of code for those who wants to find and update their old documents.

> ```
> where true and not exists(MyNewPropery)
> ```
>
> It's a little weird command as you can see in where statement, but
> this is how we can use RQL to find not existed property in a certain
> collection.

Complete code:

```
from Categories
where true and not exists(MyNewPropery)
update {
    this.MyNewPropery = "";
}
```